# Can't make a simple transaction in MariaDB /Dbeaver

Tags: mariadb, dbeaver

I'm trying to execute this

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM zones;
COMMIT;
```

Get this error.

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=1035920) You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM zones;

When trying to execute this

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO zones (name) VALUES ("ZONE 5");
INSERT INTO zones (name) VALUES ("ZONE 6");
INSERT INTO zones (name) VALUES ("ZONE 7");
COMMIT;
```

Same

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=1035920) You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO zones (name)
> VALUES ("ZONE 5");

Don't know why this is happening, I've looked for syntax errors, SQL code samples, everywhere.

MariaDB version: 10.3.30-MariaDB
Dbeaver version: Version 22.0.4.202205011839 latest.

Comment: What table storage engine is used? ... looks ok at this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=07760f4b5be37576814856318d0333c7)

Comment: The database engine is InnoDB. I've been doing some test and seems like there is something related with de RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using the "Execute sql script" button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you!. It worked indeed. Highlighted the transaction statement and pressed "Execute sql script" (ALT + X), executing only the highlighted lines and it ran all lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some test and seems like there is something related with de RDBMS. Tried to run the query in phpmyadmin and it worked fine.

Thought that it might have something to do with the RDBMS. I was trying to execute the query highlighting the whole statement.

I could run the query in Dbeaver executing line by line.

1. `START TRANSACTION;`
2. `Query statements;`
3. `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;`

Following this procedure it worked fine. Also learned that you can't execute multiple `INSERT INTO` statements all at once.